# Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugKotlin' for flutter version 2.10.5 and dart 2.16.2

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

I upgraded my flutter SDK recently and i ran my flutter app on my android device but it throws an error in my terminal.  The solutions i tried were flutter clean but it help.

```
Launching lib\main.dart on Nokia 2 3 in debug mode...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugKotlin'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.
   > Failed to transform armeabi_v7a_debug-1.0.0-57d3bac3dd5cb5b0e464ab70e7bc8a0d8cf083ab.jar (io.flutter:armeabi_v7a_debug:1.0.0-57d3bac3dd5cb5b0e464ab70e7bc8a0d8cf083ab) to match attributes {artifactType=android-classes-jar, org.gradle.category=library, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-api}.
      > Execution failed for JetifyTransform: C:\Users\user\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\io.flutter\armeabi_v7a_debug\1.0.0-57d3bac3dd5cb5b0e464ab70e7bc8a0d8cf083ab\e61133d0af3232ad460e8448e08d8ad8ea45159\armeabi_v7a_debug-1.0.0-57d3bac3dd5cb5b0e464ab70e7bc8a0d8cf083ab.jar.
         > Failed to transform 'C:\Users\user\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\io.flutter\armeabi_v7a_debug\1.0.0-57d3bac3dd5cb5b0e464ab70e7bc8a0d8cf083ab\e61133d0af3232ad460e8448e08d8ad8ea45159\armeabi_v7a_debug-1.0.0-57d3bac3dd5cb5b0e464ab70e7bc8a0d8cf083ab.jar' using Jetifier. Reason: EOFException, message: Unexpected end of ZLIB input stream. (Run with --stacktrace for more details.)
           Suggestions:
            - Check out existing issues at https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:460323&s=modified_time:desc, it's possible 
that this issue has already been filed there.
            - If this issue has not been filed, please report it at https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=460323 (run with --stacktrace and provide a stack trace if possible).
   > Failed to transform x86_debug-1.0.0-57d3bac3dd5cb5b0e464ab70e7bc8a0d8cf083ab.jar (io.flutter:x86_debug:1.0.0-57d3bac3dd5cb5b0e464ab70e7bc8a0d8cf083ab) to match attributes {artifactType=android-classes-jar, org.gradle.category=library, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-api}.
      > Execution failed for JetifyTransform: C:\Users\user\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\io.flutter\x86_debug\1.0.0-57d3bac3dd5cb5b0e464ab70e7bc8a0d8cf083ab\8e06177ed20b65ee31561fb52c74799098ed16e8\x86_debug-1.0.0-57d3bac3dd5cb5b0e464ab70e7bc8a0d8cf083ab.jar.
         > Failed to transform 'C:\Users\user\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\io.flutter\x86_debug\1.0.0-57d3bac3dd5cb5b0e464ab70e7bc8a0d8cf083ab\8e06177ed20b65ee31561fb52c74799098ed16e8\x86_debug-1.0.0-57d3bac3dd5cb5b0e464ab70e7bc8a0d8cf083ab.jar' using Jetifier. Reason: EOFException, message: Unexpected end of ZLIB input stream. (Run with --stacktrace for more details.)
           Suggestions:
            - Check out existing issues at https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:460323&s=modified_time:desc, it's possible 
that this issue has already been filed there.
            - If this issue has not been filed, please report it at https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=460323 (run with --stacktrace and provide a stack trace if possible).
   > Failed to transform x86_64_debug-1.0.0-57d3bac3dd5cb5b0e464ab70e7bc8a0d8cf083ab.jar (io.flutter:x86_64_debug:1.0.0-57d3bac3dd5cb5b0e464ab70e7bc8a0d8cf083ab) to match attributes {artifactType=android-classes-jar, org.gradle.category=library, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, 
org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-api}.
      > Execution failed for JetifyTransform: C:\Users\user\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\io.flutter\x86_64_debug\1.0.0-57d3bac3dd5cb5b0e464ab70e7bc8a0d8cf083ab\80530edc11447c3fcd6dc5022bf383395a403b31\x86_64_debug-1.0.0-57d3bac3dd5cb5b0e464ab70e7bc8a0d8cf083ab.jar.       
         > Failed to transform 'C:\Users\user\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\io.flutter\x86_64_debug\1.0.0-57d3bac3dd5cb5b0e464ab70e7bc8a0d8cf083ab\80530edc11447c3fcd6dc5022bf383395a403b31\x86_64_debug-1.0.0-57d3bac3dd5cb5b0e464ab70e7bc8a0d8cf083ab.jar' using Jetifier. Reason: EOFException, message: Unexpected end of ZLIB input stream. (Run with --stacktrace for more details.)
           Suggestions:
            - Check out existing issues at https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:460323&s=modified_time:desc, it's possible 
that this issue has already been filed there.
            - If this issue has not been filed, please report it at https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=460323 (run with --stacktrace and provide a stack trace if possible).
* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full 
insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
BUILD FAILED in 5m 7s
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...                            310.0s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

The following is my build gradle(android)

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.6.20'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.2'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

And this build gradle(app)

```
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

android {
    compileSdkVersion flutter.compileSdkVersion

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.example.gigbox"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion flutter.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {

    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

this is my flutter doctor -v

```
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.10.5, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19044.1586], locale en-US)
    • Flutter version 2.10.5 at C:\flutter and dart zips\flutter_windows_2.5.2-stable\flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision 5464c5bac7 (5 days ago), 2022-04-18 09:55:37 -0700
    • Engine revision 57d3bac3dd
    • Dart version 2.16.2
    • DevTools version 2.9.2

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 31.0.0)
    • Android SDK at C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
    • Platform android-31, build-tools 31.0.0
    • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.10+0-b96-7249189)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[√] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe

[X] Visual Studio - develop for Windows
    X Visual Studio not installed; this is necessary for Windows development.
      Download at https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/.
      Please install the "Desktop development with C++" workload, including all of its default components

[√] Android Studio (version 2020.3)
    • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.10+0-b96-7249189)

[√] VS Code (version 1.66.2)
    • VS Code at C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code
    • Flutter extension version 3.38.1

[√] Connected device (4 available)
    • Nokia 2 3 (mobile) • PT99621AA1A30201783 • android-arm    • Android 11 (API 30)
    • Windows (desktop)  • windows             • windows-x64    • Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19044.1586]
    • Chrome (web)       • chrome              • web-javascript • unknown
    • Edge (web)         • edge                • web-javascript • Microsoft Edge 100.0.1185.39

[√] HTTP Host Availability
    • All required HTTP hosts are available

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
```

This issue also started when i upgrade my flutter, then also i have noticed that my dart code formatter does not work after this upgrade. I have tried flutter downgrade and flutter clean but they have not solved the issue too.